# No funciona el Update

Tags: php, sql

Tengo una tabla `plazas` con los atributos `NUMPLAZA` , `OCUPACION` , `IDusuario`
Deseo cambiar el valor de `OCUPACION` a `OCUPADO` mediante la siguiente consulta desde php:

```
elseif ($row['Cargo'] == "directivo2") {

        $sql = "UPDATE `plazas` SET `OCUPACION`='OCUPADO' WHERE  `NUMPLAZA`='3'";;}
```

Sin embargo, no se está actualizando la fila.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da si ejecutas la query directamente en base de datos? Sin más info de la base de datos es difícil responder... Y no sé si es por código incompleto, pero faltaría en php la ejecución de la sentencia sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola no estas ejecutando la consulta agrega la linea 2 a tu codigo

```
1 $sql = "UPDATE `plazas` SET `OCUPACION`='OCUPADO' WHERE  `NUMPLAZA`='3'";
2 $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
```